# Flutter, Too many positional arguments ( but is not so )

Tags: flutter, arguments

I've declared a static method in the class API with one required argument "token".
But in Android Studio i get an error

"**error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. (extra_positional_arguments at [disconnection] lib/main.dart:28)**"

but if I run the code the method works fine, the argument is received.

If I remove the argument "TEST-ARG" the error disappear, but i get an error "Too few positional arguments" error in the app ( red screen ).

but if i remove the argument "TEST-ARG" i get an error

```
checkUser(){
    API.checkUser("TEST-ARG").then((response){
      print(response.body);
      setState(() {
        loginCheck = false;
      });
    });
}
```

API dart

```
class API {
  ....
  static Future checkUser(String token) {
  }
  ....
}
```

what am i doing wrong?
Thanks

Comment: Not a computer but I think the error is here. Have you tried changing {"token":token} to "{'token' : $token}"

Comment: I can totally remove the http.post line, it's the same

Answer (score 3):

It was a Android Studio issue. I've deleted and recreated api.dart, quit and reopen Android Studio and issue is gone

Comment: Thanks, it is a correct answer. no need delete file just quick Android studio and reopen